# I'm trying to loop in swift but I'm having problems

Tags: swift

**I tried loop but why does it only show checked ones? and test, the tick does not appear**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
      {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doSomething()
        label()
      }
        
        @IBOutlet weak var subTitle: UILabel!
        
        let text = ["test", "check", "checked"]
        
        func label(){
            for name in text {
                print(subTitle.text = (name))
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: It isn’t at all clear what you are trying to do. Your code should not compile as posted. Do you want to compare the label contents to see if it matches one of the array elements? Do you want to display each string in turn? Please update your question to describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Neither your code nor your question make much sense.

The print statement in your `label()` function should not even compile:

```
print(subTitle.text = (name))
```

What is that supposed to do? The print statement will log output to the debug console. however, the expression `subTitle.text = (name)` does not look like legal swift. Are you trying to tell if the contents of your label field contains one of the strings in your array? If so, you need to use `==` (comparison) not `=` (assignment.)

Try:

```
print("label text = \(name) ==", subTitle.text == (name))
```